# Adding a gif to a larger background

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using imagemagick to resize uploaded files but while they're processing I want to show a rotating gif wheel to the user where the thumbnail would normally be. I serve about 7 sizes of thumbs and would like the wheel to remain at it's 32x32 size in the middle, that's the simple bit.

What I need to know is, can I do the above while still retaining the animation

Example:

This Image:
[image: This Image]

Starting at this size
[image: This Size]

With Animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a solution in php witch i use to watermark gif animated images ....
it create an black bacground  put an image on it and then put watermark ...

```
watermarkpath = 'path to wathermarkimage.jpg|gif|png';
$imagepath= 'path to the image';     
$watermark = new Imagick($watermarkpath);
 $GIF = new Imagick();
 $GIF->setFormat("gif");

$animation = new Imagick($imagepath);
foreach ($animation as $frame) {

    $iWidth = $frame->getImageWidth();
    $iHeight = $frame->getImageHeight();
    $wWidth = $watermark->getImageWidth();
    $wHeight = $watermark->getImageHeight();

    if ($iHeight < $wHeight || $iWidth < $wWidth) {
        // resize the watermark
        $watermark->scaleImage($iWidth, $iHeight);

        // get new size
        $wWidth = $watermark->getImageWidth();
        $wHeight = $watermark->getImageHeight();
    }

    $bgframe = new Imagick();
    $bgframe->newImage(($iWidth), ($iHeight + 80), new ImagickPixel('Black'));
    $bgframe->setImageDelay($frame->getImageDelay());


    $x = ($iWidth) - $wWidth - 5;
    $y = ($iHeight + 80) - $wHeight - 5;


    $bgframe->compositeImage($frame, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
     $bgframe->flattenImages();
    $bgframe->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $x, $y);
     $bgframe->flattenImages();
    $GIF->addImage($bgframe);
}



$GIF->writeimages($imagepath,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle, it might contain what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/TGdFB/1/

It uses jQuery, but should be easily adaptable...

Comment: I've looked into using a css solution, it's not going to work well with our current code structure though. If it was more important I could warrant a change and use css/jquery but this is only going to be shown while a file is queued, then thumbnails are generated anyway.

Comment: It might help, if you'd post a fiddle of what you already have. Don't you want to have any javascript at all? You surely have some kind of callback when your image is processed, or how would you swap images? *confused*

Comment: Well what I'm trying to do is just generate these files just once, the processing is done by another process reading from a job list in mysql. Consider this a static image, in place of a thumbnail which is yet to be generated. Some of the content upload could be large video files which get converted into two different formats before generating images, this could take a while depending on several factors. So instead of displaying a black square while the user browses their content page, I want to show one of these thumbnails. Thanks though, I see what you're trying to explain to me!

Comment: So you create a thumbnail with that loading image and replace it at some time, when your thumb generation is finished, so the loading image and the thumb have the same filename? In this case, I'd suggest to create the loading thumb in the same size as the final thumb will be.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up doing this manually by Photoshop after not being able to find an automated way of doing this through imagemagick. I found the 'coalesce' flag but not much else.